# Kinetic scrolling a List<Rectangle> in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to scroll a series of rectangles vertically. Each rectangle has a fixed distance from the next. The first rectangle must never be below 10 pixels from the top of the screen while similarly the last rectangle must never be more than 20 pixels above a text box. In other words, I am mimicking the SMS application in Windows Phone.

The method below should, in theory, scroll the rectangles kinetically, and while it does, in some cases some of the rectangles come closer to each other than they should (eventually overlapping). The effect seems to be magnified when flicks on screen are slow.

```
private void Flick()
{
    int toMoveBy = (int)flickDeltaY;
    //flickDeltaY is assigned in the HandleInput() method as shown below
    //flickDeltaY = s.Delta.Y * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
    {
        ChatMessage message = messages[i];
        if (i == 0 && flickDeltaY > 0)
        {
            if (message.Bounds.Y + flickDeltaY > 10)
            {
                toMoveBy = 10 - message.Bounds.Top;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == messages.Count - 1 && flickDeltaY < 0)
        {
            if (message.Bounds.Bottom + flickDeltaY < textBox.Top - 20)
            {
                toMoveBy = textBox.Top - 20 - message.Bounds.Bottom;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (ChatMessage cm in messages)
    {
        Vector2 target = new Vector2(cm.Bounds.X, cm.Bounds.Y + toMoveBy);
        Vector2 newPos = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(cm.Bounds.X, cm.Bounds.Y), target, 0.5F);
        float omega = 0.05f;
        if (Vector2.Distance(newPos, target) < omega)
        {
            newPos = target;
        }
        cm.Bounds = new Rectangle((int)newPos.X, (int)newPos.Y, cm.Bounds.Width, cm.Bounds.Height);
    }
}
```

I really don't understand Vectors so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really fully understand what you are trying to achieve. But I found in your code a problem : your linear interpolation (`Vector2.Lerp`) doesn't really makes sense (or am I missing something ?) :

```
Vector2 target = new Vector2(cm.Bounds.X, cm.Bounds.Y + toMoveBy); // <-- the target is Y-ToMoveBy different from the actual Y position
Vector2 newPos = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(cm.Bounds.X, cm.Bounds.Y), target, 0.5F); // <-- this line is equivalent to say that newPos will be new Vector2(cm.Bounds.X, cm.Bounds.Y + toMoveBy / 2);
float omega = 0.05f;
if (Vector2.Distance(newPos, target) < omega) // So the only chance to happen is toMoveBy == 0.10 ??? (because you modify `cm` each time `Flick()` is called ? - see next line) 
{
    newPos = target;
}
cm.Bounds = new Rectangle((int)newPos.X, (int)newPos.Y, cm.Bounds.Width, cm.Bounds.Height); // <-- Equivalent to  new Rectangle((int)cm.Bounds.X, (int)cm.Bounds.Y + toMoveBy / 2, ...)
```

Comment: Well basically I just want to be able to kinetically scroll a list of Rectangle objects based on touch inputs. This is an XNA implementation of a very similar interface to a threaded SMS application. Also I didn't quite understand your answer; I added the if condition because I read on somewhere that `Lerp` will not reach the target, only get very close to it, so the threshold `omega` is there so that as it gets close enough to the target it just assigns it. It might still be wrong though.